# Processing data between Model and View in Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm starting in Asp.NEt MVC , and I'm trying to create a login page for my application. I'm using MVC 4, EF 5, MySQL (I can't use newer versions because of my hosting provider restrictions).

I'm using Database first approach, and in my database I have a Users table with a Email and password field. The problem is that I want the password to be stored in a varbinary field, so the model is generated with a byte[] property.

In my View, I'm using:
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)

In the controller, I have the following Login method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user, string returnUrl)
{
    // Lets first check if the Model is valid or not
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext())
        {
            string username = user.Email;
            byte[] password = user.Password;
            (...)
```

How can take the password the user typed and Encrypt it and turn it into a byte array beforing passing it to the model?

Comment: Why don't you just make a function that consumes a textual password and returns a byte array? (byte[] password = encrypt(User.Password)). Your model should just be a representation of what has been entered in the UI.

Comment: The question is that my model reflects what is in my table, so user.password is byte[], not string. Should I create 2 different models? One for the view and another for the table?

Comment: Yes, you should. Your model is a 'view model' and should represent what should be displayed in the view. Depending on what you use to access your database (Entity Framework or another ORM?), you probable also have domain objects that represent your tables.